# 'uniform approximation' of real in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Good evening,

Prove that: For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist an $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for every $x\in[0,1]$, there exist $(p,q)\in \mathbb{N^2}$, with $0\leq p\leq q\leq n$ and |$qx−p|≤\varepsilon$.

I have tried to prove the result like the proof of density but I didn't succeed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are $n$ and $N$ the same number here? Also, what is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @ThomasE Sorry, I edited

Comment: Maybe what you want to prove is that *For every $\varepsilon >0$, there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for every $x \in [0,1]$, there exist $(p,q) \in \mathbb{N^2}$, with $0 \leq p \leq q \leq n$ and $|qx-p| \leq \varepsilon$*.

Comment: @YiogosSSmyrlis It was poorly written, Yes that is exactly what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to prove is:

*For every $\varepsilon >0$, there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for every $x \in [0,1]$, there exist $(p,q) \in \mathbb{N^2}$, with $0 \leq p \leq q \leq n$ and $|qx-p| \leq \varepsilon$*,

then this is indeed true, and we simply need to take $n=\frac{1}{\lfloor \varepsilon\rfloor+1}$.

Let $x_j=jx-\lfloor jx\rfloor$, $j=1,\ldots,n$. Then $x_j\in [0,1]$, and as these are $n$ numbers in $[0,1]$, there should be a pair of them with difference less or equal to $1/n$, i.e.,
$$
|x_j-x_k|\le\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon, \quad \text{for some}\,\,\, 1\le j<k\le n.
$$
That means
$$
|(k-j)x-(\lfloor kx\rfloor-\lfloor jx\rfloor)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Hence, indeed the Fact is true for $q=k-j$ and $p=\lfloor kx\rfloor-\lfloor jx\rfloor$.

Comment: Sorry but with this choice, you get $|qx-p|<1$ and not $|qx-p|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I was thinking the same..

Comment: @Julien: Corrected!

Comment: @Arash You are right! I corrected it!

Comment: @Julien: New Correction! Sorry - I hope this time it is OK :)

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Yes, very smart! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Approximation_Theorem).